# GLIB segfault: No source available for "g_slice_alloc() "

Tags: c, glib

This segfault happens when I am running:

```
alignarray *aligns = g_ptr_array_sized_new(N_DEFAULT_ALIGNS);
```

..., where `alignarray` is just `GPtrArray`.

This statement runs successfully for several times, and then suddenly fails, reporting *"No source available for `g_slice_alloc()`"*. After searching, I try to use `export G_SLICE=always-malloc` to disable the slicing memory allocation, but it still fails...

Or is it because somewhere in the code I did not handle the memory well? Currently my problem is that I do not know where to debug. I tried *gdb* and *valgrind*, but both cannot help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that setting `G_SLICE=always-malloc` still gives this problem. The slice allocator is a way of avoiding the overhead of allocating memory by reusing memory for actions that are similarly sized.

If you allocate 100 things that are 8 bytes long (like 2 pointers on 32-bit) free those and allocate some more then you'll reuse the same memory. The big caveat is that you must ensure that memory that was allocated using the slice allocator is freed using the slice allocator functions - directly through `g_slice_free` or indirectly through something like `g_object_unref` Check in your code that you're not freeing other instances of `GPtrArray` (or something of a similar size) with `g_free`

You may be able to identify where the erroneous freeing or corruption is occurring using valgrind. When using valgrind you *must* set `G_SLICE=always-malloc`